# How do I resize my view in horizontal orientation?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

In portrait orientation my view is 744px in height. I want to change this height when it is in landscape view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the sizing inspector in Interface Builder, set the "struts & springs" for the resizing behaviour you want.  If you want to control the size by code, just create a `CGRect` and set the view's frame to the rect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` method in your view controller. In the overriden method you need to call superclass method and then resize your view appropriately.